# Control de Excepciones

Tags: c#, excepciones, try-catch

Hola a todos tengo una pregunta, imaginemos que tenemos 3 clases
la cual 1 es un Form de C# este form llama a un metodo de la clase 2 y la clase 2 llama a un metodo de la clase 3 que puede arrojar alguna excepcion, mi pregunta es ¿En que lugar es mejor controlar la excepcion de un metodo para mostrar el mensaje de error al usuario? En el form o en la clase 2?

```
//Ejemplo Form
private void MetodoForm(){
  new Clase2().MetodoClase2();
 //Mostrar Mensaje de error 
//mas acciones
}
//Ejemplo Clase2
public void MetodoClase2(){
  new Clase3().MetodoClase3();
  
  //mas acciones
}
//Ejemplo Clase3
public void MetodoClase3(){
  //puede causar una excepcion
  File.WriteAllText("Texto");
  //mas acciones
}
```

he pensado en esta opcion pero siento que no tiene sentido ya que estoy generando una excepcion dentro de un catch

```
//Ejemplo Form
private void MetodoForm(){
 try{
    new Clase2().MetodoClase2();
   //Mostrar Mensaje de error 
   //mas acciones
 catch(ExcepcionCreadaPorMi e){//MostrarMensaje}
}

//Ejemplo Clase2
public void MetodoClase2(){
  try{
     new Clase3().MetodoClase3();
     //mas acciones
  }catch(IOException e){Throw new ExcepcionCreadaPorMi("Error al escribir el mensaje");}

}

//Ejemplo Clase3
public void MetodoClase3(){
  //puede causar una excepcion
  File.WriteAllText("Texto");
  //mas acciones
}
```

Comment: No hay una sola respuesta, solo podríamos dar opiniones. Yo te diría que tu método de la clase 3 devolviera un `bool`, capturaras ahí mismo la excepción y en ese caso devolver `false`, invocarlo dentro de un `if` en la clase 2 y devolver una respuesta acorde a la clase 1, pero de nuevo, solo es una opinión. Preguntas así pueden ser cerradas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En cuanto a mostrar el error al usuario se recomienda hacerlo en el form ya que tienes herramientas como Messagebox.Show("mensaje") que lo muestra por pantalla o incluso poder personalizarlo.
Tendrías tres bloques try catch uno en cada clase en donde lanzarias la excepción para "arriba" hasta el ultimo try catch (en este caso el form) y lo mostrarias por pantalla.
Hay que tomar en cuenta que si eres el programador y miras un error que es poco informativo se dificulta saber el origen y el detalle del problema, pero para estos casos se puede hacer que en el origen de la excepcion (la clase 3) puedas guardar el mensaje en un log como un txt y ahi veras el detalle del problema (librerías como Log4net)
Codigo:

```
         private void MetodoForm()
         {
            try
            {
                new Clase2().MetodoClase2();
            catch (ExcepcionCreadaPorMi ex)
            {
                //como no hay mas try catch entonces aqui terminaria el flujo de la excepcion
                //le damos personalizacion al mensaje. Si por ejemplo es crear un cliente...
                Messagebox.show("Ocurrio un error al crear un cliente");
            }
         }

        
        public void MetodoClase2()
        {
            try
            {
                new Clase3().MetodoClase3();
                //mas acciones
            }
            catch (ExcepcionCreadaPorMi ex)
            {
                //Cae la excepcion que nos lanzó la clase 3
                //lanzamos la excepcion para arriba
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        
        public void MetodoClase3()
        {
            try
            {
                File.WriteAllText("Texto");
            }
            catch (ExcepcionCreadaPorMi ex)
            {
                //Guardamos la excepcion en un txt con el detalle de lo que ocurrió
                Logger.Info(ex.Message);
                //Lanzamos la excepcion para arriba y en caso de que exista un try catch caera al catch y asi sucesivamente
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Espero que haya sido de ayuda, Saludos!